# CSS, Bootstrap, HTML5

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a **single page website**. Framework used by me is **Bootstrap**.  My question is regarding **navigation bar**.  I want my navigation-bar to be transparent on first-page and as I  scroll down it should become visible and be fixed as I continue to scroll down.

I am able to make it transparent on first-page but I am unable to make it appear on second page. It remains transparent.

Pls help me. I am a newbie. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some code, what you've tried, things we can build off of to help you. You've provided nothing for us to help you with.

Comment: A single page app with a second page?

Comment: like this http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/xVzYdO

Answer (score 1):

You can make two navbars one will be transparent and one will be the fixed one and then use JavaScript onScroll and display CSS property for removing and adding your navigations.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have to use JavaScript. If I understand right and you want the navbar on top transparent and if you begin to scroll no more transparent and then fixed to top?

Comment: yes u get it right. i want it to appear transparent on first page and from second page it should be fixed